# web2py view error

Tags: upload, web2py

I am new to web2py and I have to write a file upload script.

now searching trough internets i found a script and it kind of works local on my cmp
After putting it to server i get invalid view (uploda_zipa/upload_file.html)

The code is:

```
  import datetime



  timestamp = datetime.datetime.today()
                db.define_table('files',
                Field('title', 'string'),
                Field('uploaded_data', 'upload'),
                Field('created_on','datetime',default=timestamp))

  db.files.title.requires = IS_NOT_EMPTY()                
  db.files.uploaded_data.requires = IS_NOT_EMPTY()
  #Now, lets add an action the our controller

  def upload_file():
    url = ""

    form = SQLFORM(db.files, showid=False)
    if form.accepts(request.vars, session):
       response.flash = T('File uploaded successfully!')
       url = URL(r=request, f="download", 
             args = db(db.files.title ==   request.vars.title).select(orderby=~db.files.created_on)[0].uploaded_data)

    return dict(form=form, cknum=request.vars.CKEditorFuncNum, url=url)
```

I would also like to know how to set path for folder in which files should be uploaded or is that default way. The plan is smth like a file gets uploaded to a specific folder and than it gets processed by a different script

thank you

Answer (score 2):

If you do not have an 'upload_file.html' view defined, web2py will fall back to using the 'generic.html' view. However, by default, the generic views are only enabled on localhost, so that probably explains why it worked on your local computer but not once uploaded to the server. For security reasons, it is recommended that you not enable generic views on production, or at least that you do so judiciously. See [here](http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/09#Generic-Views) for more details.

As for the upload folder, it defaults to /yourapp/uploads, though you can change it as follows:

```
import os
db.define_table('files',
    Field('uploaded_data', 'upload',
        uploadfolder=os.path.join(request.folder, 'path', 'to', 'uploads')))
```

See the explanation of `uploadfolder` in the list of [arguments to `Field()`](http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/06#Record-Representation).

Comment: Seems like web2py always creates a table to track files.
Is it possible not to create this table and second I would like the file to have its original name. Now I did it with with os.rename
Is there any other way?

Comment: web2py does not create the table to track files -- you create the table and add an upload field to it. You can upload files without a database table using SQLFORM.factory. The file is renamed for security reasons, though the original filename is b16encoded within a portion of the new filename, so it can be decoded (the built-in download mechanism does this automatically).

Comment: If you want to override the automatic naming (which does present a security risk), you can skip the form validation (which handles the file saving) and process the file upload yourself (request.vars.field is a cgi.FieldStorage object -- the file object is in request.vars.field.file).